# How to set the `BUNDLE_PATH` value related to the RVM "Integration via ':default_environment'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rvm

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid, Ruby 1.9.3p125, Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and [RVM](https://rvm.io) 1.10.3. I am trying to properly set the `BUNDLE_PATH` value related to the RVM "[Integration via ':default_environment'](https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano)".

At this time in my `deploy.rb` file I have (note the commented `BUNDLE_PATH` hash key):

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH'         => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => '1.9.3p125',
  'GEM_HOME'     => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125",
  'GEM_PATH'     => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global"
  # 'BUNDLE_PATH'  => '/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01'  # If you are using bundler.
}
```

Since I am using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage my gems, I would like to set that value as well as it should be made. **What is really BUNDLE_PATH? How can I set that (that is, what value I must consider)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the first section of integration with [**capistrano plugin**](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/)

Also there is integration gem with bundler - I have used both in my example app - https://github.com/mpapis/ad

If you update RVM to head version in your system and on server you can use the new method of reading ruby version from configuration file, start with update:

```
rvm get head
```

Then check this line of deploy.rb: https://github.com/mpapis/ad/blob/master/config/deploy.rb#L9

And use one of the new configuration files not needing trusting: https://github.com/mpapis/ad/blob/master/Gemfile

```
#ruby=1.9.3-p125
#ruby-gemset=my-app
```

This should automatically select your ruby from `Gemfile` comment, just do not forget to remove `.rvmrc` as it's for now selected as the primary format to specify your ruby.

Comment: I am in trouble on setting the proper `ree@rails3` value related to the `set :rvm_ruby_string` statement present in the linked content (*BTW*: that's why I chose to use the second form). **How can I set the `ree@rails3` value in my case?**

Comment: *Repeat*: **How can I set the ree@rails3 value in my case?**

Comment: `set :rvm_ruby_string, "ree@rails3"` - but remember this is remote environment, it does not istall this ruby and does not create this gemset - you need to do that on server